# In a field, prove that if $ x + x = 0$ then $ 1 +1 = 0$

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory

Question:

Suppose F is a field and that $ x$ cannot equal $ 0$. Prove that if $ x+x=0$ then $ 1 +1=0$.

My attempt:

*We know $x^{-1}$ exists  because $x$ cannot equal*  $0$.

$ x^{-1}\left(x+x\right)=\ x^{-1}.0$

$ x^{-1}.x  + x^{-1}.x =0$,  *by  distributivity*.

$1  +1  = 0$,  *by multiplicative  inverse*.

I am not quite sure if this is the correct way to prove it. If it is incorrect could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks great. ${} $

Comment: I'm no expert in field theory, but this looks completely fine to me.

Comment: Aside: `\cdot` will give you a better formatted dot, so you can write $x^{-1} \cdot x$ rather than $x^{-1}.x$. Also, only put `$..$` signs around the individual formulas, so you don't ruin the surrounding text.

Comment: Looks OK to me!

Comment: $0=x+x=(1+1)\,x$

Comment: Am I right that $GF(2)$ is the only field where this can happen?

Comment: @jgsmath it happens in every field of characteristic $2$, and there are more such fields other than $GF(2)$... See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645614/examples-of-fields-with-characteristic-2

Comment: It's fine.  You need a proposition that $0*x=0$ but you probably have proved that.  Another useful basic fact is $x*y=0 \iff x=0$ or $y=0$.  So $0=x+x=x (1+1) $.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that is a bit more general but based on the same idea, holds in any integral domain : if $x$ is non zero then it is regular and so $x+x =0 \implies x\cdot (1+1)=0$, and so by regularity, $1+1=0$

Answer (score 1):

The real challenge here is to find a significant variant of Josh Mitkitzel's proof.  But insofar as questions need answers, here's what popped into my head:

$1 + 1 = x^{-1}x + x^{-1}x = x^{-1}(x + x) = x^{-1}\cdot 0 = 0. \tag{1}$

A *bona fide* one-liner!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the finite field is the $GF(q^k)$ and $x\neq0$ is the element of this field, then we have
$$
x+x=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x=(q-1)x  \quad \Rightarrow \quad 1=q-1
\quad \Rightarrow \quad q=2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 1+1=0
$$